# Access a Dictionary item in a view when using SSVE in Nancy

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, nancy

I'm passing a Dictionary to my view. But I am not able to access the objects in the dictionary.

How do we read a Dictionary in a view when using SSVE in Nancy? Here's my code:

**HelpModule**

```
public class HelpModule : NancyModule
{
    public HelpModule()
    {
        Get["/help/"] = _ => View["index"];
        Get["/help/faqs/"] = parameters => {
            return Negotiate
                .WithModel(new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    { "model" , new RatPack { FirstName = "Nancy " } },
                    { "info" , new RatPack { FirstName = "Info " } }
                })
                .WithView("faqs")
                .WithHeader("X-Custom", "SomeValue");
        };
    }
}

public class RatPack
{
    public string FirstName;
}
```

**View**

```
@Each
    @Current
@EndEach
```

The output I get is

> [model, WebService.Website.Website.Modules.Help.RatPack] [info, WebService.Website.Website.Modules.Help.RatPack]

I tried the following:

```
@Each
    @Current["info"]
@EndEach

@Each
    @Current.info
@EndEach
```

But I am not getting the data.

Comment: Just a stab in the dark, but I am assuming that in the context of the loop, `@Current` is a `KeyValuePair<string,RatPack>`.  Therefore, would `@Current.Value` work?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @erdomke's [Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48339312/access-a-dictionary-in-a-view-when-using-nancy#comment84328103_48339312), we can use `@Current.Value`.

As follows:

```
@Each
    @Current.Key: @Current.Value.Firstname
@EndEach
```

Which will give the output:

> model: Nancy info: Info